# Unclear indentation using mixins in pug

Tags: html, pug

In future projects i want to use Pug(jade), but i saw one problem:
I write small mixin:[1]

```
mixin item(href, active)
 if(active)
    li(class="active"): a( href=href ): block
 else   
    li: a( href=href ): block
```

Here we call it: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ythV.png)

```
+item("#sec1")
```

Output result: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xUHG.png)

```
<div class="vak-xs-12 vak-md-5 vnav-menu">
    <ul>
          <li><a href="#sec1">rwa</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Someone know how to remove this indentations?

Comment: You don't want your output html formatted? Can you post what your desired result is?

Comment: I need to remove indentation 4 unclear indentation.
[I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xUHG.png) - with indentation.

[I need](http://joxi.ru/gmvOKB1uW7PG2a) - without indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the editor, you have to configure it to use always the same number of spaces and you have to use the 'tab' key instead of spaces.

Comment: [Click here, menu of ST3](http://joxi.ru/eAOMv9EUP0Rpmo)
I also think that this is due to the editor. I convert indentation to "tabs", but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the conditional. Have you tried something like:

```
mixin item(href, active)
  li(class= (true === active) ? 'active')
    a(href= href)
      if block
        block
```